# Running Stylecop.MSBuild on Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, stylecop

For some reason I cant get StyleCop to run during the build in Visual Studio 2015

I have installed the StyleCop.MSBuild package, added the StyleCopTreatErrorsAsWarnings tag to my project file, and checked the Import tag exists for the targets (as documented everywhere I look).
However when I run the build I don't get a peep.

Is there something I've missed?
Is there a problem with it working on VS2015? 
Is there a fix or anything I can do to get it to work?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the relevant bits of the project file?

Comment: I have StyleCop.MSBuild working in VS 2015 in several different projects.